# SEVERE: Context [/OnetoMany] startup failed due to previous errors

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

In my project i want two tables connected by OneToMany relationship but when i add these lines( @OneToMany(mappedBy = "CustomerDetails", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set product;) it throws some errors instead of OneToMany if i use OneToOne it works fine but i want onetomany and my concept is one customer can place many orders..

Exception

> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener
> instance of class
> [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: **Error
> creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class**
> com.xxx.spring.config.ApplicationConfig: Invocation of init method
> failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
> [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit:
> default] **Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory**     at
> org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1225)
> at
> org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.access$600(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:119)
> at
> org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:853)
> at
> org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
> at
> org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: **mappedBy reference an
> unknown target entity property:**
> com.xxx.spring.entity.Product.CustomerDetails in
> com.changepond.spring.entity.CustomerDetails.product  at
> org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:768)
> at
> org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:728)
> at
> org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:70)
> at
> org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1695)
>
> **SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file** Jul 04, 2022 5:08:53 PM
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
> **SEVERE: Context [/OnetoMany] startup failed due to previous errors** Jul 04, 2022 5:08:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext
> log INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext Jul 04, 2022
> 5:08:54 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase
> clearReferencesJdbc WARNING: The web application [OnetoMany]
> registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] but failed to
> unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a
> memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered. Jul 04,
> 2022 5:08:54 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase
> clearReferencesThreads WARNING: The web application [OnetoMany]
> appears to have started a thread named
> [mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup] but has failed to stop it.
> This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
> java.base@11.0.15/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
> java.base@11.0.15/java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:155)

CustomerDetails

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CustomerDetails")
public class CustomerDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="CUSTOMER_ID")
    private Long custid;

    @Column(name="CUSTOMER_NAME")
    private String customerName;
    
    @Column(name="EMAIL")
    private String email;
    
    @Column(name="ADDRESS")
    private String address;
    
    @Column(name="PHONENO")
    private String phoneno;
    
    public CustomerDetails() {
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "CustomerDetails", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Product> product;
    
    
 
    public CustomerDetails(String customername, String email, String address, String phoneno) {
        super();
        this.customerName = customername;
        this.email = email;
        this.address = address;
        this.phoneno = phoneno;
    }

    public Long getCustid() {
        return custid;
    }

    public void setCustid(Long custid) {
        this.custid = custid;
    }

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPhoneno() {
        return phoneno;
    }

    public void setPhoneno(String phoneno) {
        this.phoneno = phoneno;
    }
```

product

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Product")
public class Product {

    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="PRODUCT_ID")
    private Long productId;
    
    @Column(name="PRODUCT_NAME")
    private String productName;
    
    @Column(name="PRODUCT_BRAND")
    private String productBrand;
    
    @Column(name="PRODUCT_PRICE")
    private double productPrice;
    
    
    public Product(String productName, String productType, double productPrice) {
        super();
        this.productName = productName;
        this.productBrand = productType;
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
    }

    public Long getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(Long productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public String getProductBrand() {
        return productBrand;
    }

    public void setProductBrand(String productBrand) {
        this.productBrand = productBrand;
    }

    public double getProductPrice() {
        return productPrice;
    }

    public void setProductPrice(double productPrice) {
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
    }
```

Application config

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.xxx.spring.*" })
@EnableJpaRepositories (value = "com.xxx.spring.repo")
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        driverManagerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springsecurityproject");
        driverManagerDataSource.setUsername("root");
        driverManagerDataSource.setPassword("root");
        return driverManagerDataSource;
    }
    
    @Bean(name="transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager  dbTransactionManager()
    {
        
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        return transactionManager;
        
    }
    
    @Bean
    //@Autowired
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() 
    {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        
         jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update"); //validate/create/update/create-drop
         jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"); //It specifies the dialect which allows Hibernate to generate the SQL statements for the relational database.
         jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache","false"); //it can be used to completely disable the second-level cache, which is enabled by default.
         jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache","false");//It enables the query cache.
         
          factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
          factory.setPackagesToScan("com.xxx.spring.entity");
          factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
          factory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
          
          return factory;
             
    }       
}
```

Comment: Your `Product` class has no reference to  `CustomerDetails` at all

Comment: The `mappedBy` attribute is used for bi-directional relations, Aka if you want to use it you need to define a `@ManyToOne` relationship `private CustomerDetails customerDetails` inside `Product` and then use `mappedBy = "customerDetails"`. If you just want a unidirectional relationship then forget about the `mappedBy` attribute.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS   ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private CustomerDetails customerDetails;  After adding these two lines in product entity class same error remains

Comment: Did you change the `mappedBy` to lowercase `customerDetails` as in my example? In your example you used `mappedBy = "CustomerDetails"` but i changed it to `mappedBy = "customerDetails"` because fields in java should not start with upper case letter. The important thing is that you understand what the `mappedBy` attribute does and decide if you even want it all (You don't need it for unidirecitonal relations!)

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS  Thankyou so much i did mistake in mappedBy error solved thankyou!!

Answer (score 0):

MappedBy Attribute is used for bi-directional relations as mentioned in comments.

Spring handles bi-directional relations ( in your case ) creating customer_id column in products table and assigns user to different products.
Again, those products will ONLY be assigned to that specific user.

It means those products can not be assigned to other users.

Real life example:
this code will be like a store which sales only unique items to people. In this store there is only one carpet, one car, one pc and ...
If you sell (assign) any item in the store, that's it you are out of it, Although a person can by multiple stuff. Even if you create an exact replica of the original product they are still not the same.(different ids!)

If you are after this methodology your code lacks a pointer in `product`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Product")
public class Product {


  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name="PRODUCT_ID")
  private Long productId;

  @Column(name="PRODUCT_NAME")
  private String productName;

  @Column(name="PRODUCT_BRAND")
  private String productBrand;

  @Column(name="PRODUCT_PRICE")
  private double productPrice;

  @ManyToOne
  private CustomerDetails CustomerDetails;


  public Product(String productName, String productType, double productPrice) {
      super();
      this.productName = productName;
      this.productBrand = productType;
      this.productPrice = productPrice;
  }

  public Long getProductId() {
      return productId;
  }

  public void setProductId(Long productId) {
      this.productId = productId;
  }

  public String getProductName() {
      return productName;
  }

  public void setProductName(String productName) {
      this.productName = productName;
  }

  public String getProductBrand() {
      return productBrand;
  }

  public void setProductBrand(String productBrand) {
      this.productBrand = productBrand;
  }

  public double getProductPrice() {
      return productPrice;
  }

  public void setProductPrice(double productPrice) {
      this.productPrice = productPrice;
  }

  public CustomerDetails getCustomerDetails() {
      return this.CustomerDetails;
  }

  public void setCustomerDetails(CustomerDetails customerDetails) {
      this.CustomerDetails= customerDetails;
  }

}
```

Also, to avoid `NullPointerExeptions` in further expanding your project, instantiate  `private Set<Product> product;` in `customerDetails` entity and thus you do not need to set setter for that as you already have set that. From now on you can call it using getter and add `Products` to it.